# jQuery click not working in ajax html response (Django)

Tags: jquery, django, click

I have the following code:

```
<input class="span7" type="text" id="search" name="search">
<div class="well" id="search-results" style="position: absolute;
          top: 208px;
          left: 62px;
          height: 100px;
          width: 340px;
          overflow:
          auto;">
    <ul id="list-results" style="margin: 0; padding:0; top: 0;">
    {% include 'search-results.html' %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The search-result.html is displayed via ajax, when a keyup is done in an input field. An ajax request appends into the ul an element like this:

```
<li id="{{article.id}}"><a id="result-selected" href="#">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
```

When I use this function works (it's displaying in the console):

```
$('#list-results').click(function(e){
      console.log($(this));
  });
```

When I select one of these instead, it doesn't:

```
$('#list-results ul')
$('#list-results > ul')
$('#result-selected')
and more...
```

Is this a problem that this html is rendered by ajax but it's not at the begging when the page is loaded? What can I do? I want to take the values of the displayed a to do something.

Ajax call:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"/meal/search/",
          data:{
              'search_text': $('#search').val(),
              'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
          },
          success: searchSuccess,
          dataType: 'html'

      }

      );
  });

  function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

      if ($('#search').val().length < 3){
        $('#search-results').hide();
      } else {
        $('#search-results').show();
      }

      $('#list-results').html(data);

  }
```

Comment: You can't get something that isn't there. If the elements aren't inserted yet, but will be added with ajax later, there is no way to get values or text until they are actually there.

Comment: It's not working even when a long list sent via ajax are in the html. I can selected with firebug. I do a query in the input text, it's matching something so a list is displayed, then I click one of the items.

Comment: Where is the `ajax` call? It would be better if we could see it.

Comment: Either you're using the same ID multiple times, or you're trying to send the value of an element to the serverside, and then get the element which value you're trying to send in the same ajax call. The logic escapes me ?

Comment: I get the value of #search and send it to the serverside. It response with html with the items that matched the text. Then the user selects one of this item and use it in other form (This is not implemented yet). Sorry if I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with dynamic click function use

```
on('click', function ..) or live('click', function())
```

Change your function to live click

```
$('#list-results ul').live('click', function(e){
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Neither of them works. The live has a TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'live' handler http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('#list-results ul li').on('click', function(e){
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Above function will trigger when ever you click on li element within list-results div.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).live is not a function, isn't depreciated?

Comment: Oh yes, I have changed my function now it uses 'on'. Old habits die hard. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/live-is-deprecated-but-on-doesn-t-work-on-not-existent-markup

You have to first select the parent and then the yet-not-there element.

```
$('#list-results').on( 'click', '#result-selected', function(){
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).html());
  });
```